# Sleep() terminates thread in WindRiver

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, sleep, wind-river-workbench

I have to write a little programm in C with WindRiver, which creates three threads:

- Thread #1: creates a random number
- Thread #2: kill #3 if the random number is smaller 25
- Thread #3: kill #2 if the random number is greater 25

To kill a thread, I want to wait to make sure it is created, so I found that I could use `sleep()` to let another thread takes over and let it create itself. But they all die with the sleep.

I came up with this code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>    

#define NUM_THREAD 3

int theRandomNumber = 0;

void *RandomNumber (void *threadid){
    int id = (int) threadid;
    //srand();
    theRandomNumber = rand() % 50; 
    printf("Thread %d: Random: %d \n", id, theRandomNumber);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
}

void *CheckNumber (void *threadid){
  int id = (int) threadid;
  printf("Thread #%d is active and going to sleep now\n", id);
  sleep(1000);
  //here he dies without annoucing anything or something
  printf("Thread #%d is active again and back from sleep\n", id);
  if (id == 1){
      if (theRandomNumber >= 25){
          pthread_cancel(2);
          printf("THREAD %d: Thread #2 is closed \n", id);
      }
  }
  else{
      if (theRandomNumber < 25){
          pthread_cancel(1);
          printf("THREAD %d: Thread #1 is closed \n", id);
      }
  }
  return 0;
}


int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
  pthread_t threads[NUM_THREAD];
  int t = 0;

  printf("in main: create thread #%d \n", t);
  pthread_create (&threads[t], NULL, RandomNumber, (void *) t++);

  printf("in main: create thread #%d \n", t);
  pthread_create (&threads[t], NULL, CheckNumber, (void *) t++);

  printf("in main: create thread #%d \n", t);
  pthread_create (&threads[t], NULL, CheckNumber, (void *) t++);
}
```

The part with the `Randomnumber` works fine, I left it out here but I can post it on request.

After a thread reaches the `sleep()`, it's getting terminated.

Console Log:

> in main: create thread #0 
>  in main: create thread #1 
>  in main:
>   create thread #2 
>  Thread #0: Random: 8 
>  Thread #1 is active
>   and going to sleep now
>  Thread #2 is active and going to sleep
>   now

Nothing happens after sleep. Any ideas?

Comment: That's not the point here, but if you don't process program arguments, use the `main` prototype with no arguments, aka `int main()`

Comment: It would appear your main program is ending

Comment: I tried compiling your code, there are errors. Could you please provide a code ones can compile?

Comment: @CarlH with windriver it's a realtimesystem. the first created thread starts after the main is finished - no multitasking

Comment: Standard tells us, that C program terminates when main() exits. You can't have threads survivning main. Looks like multithreading is simply not an option for you here.

Comment: Besides all issues: Do not try to sync threads via calls to `sleep()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave `main()` by calling `pthread_exit()`, to only exit the "main" thread, else ending `main()` ends the process and with this all its remaining threads.

Alternatively let `main()` join all threads via calling `pthread_join()` on each PThread-id returned by the calls to `pthread_create()`.

Comment: you are right - when the `main` ends, the other threads are terminated as well. Fixed this with the  `pthread_join()` - now my `pthread_cancel()`is stucking, but that's an other problem. Thanks!